# How can I override comcast's wonky DNS settings in the router resolv.conf?

Tags: router, dhcp

Whenever I connect my laptop to my Xfinity router (TC8305C), it writes wonky settings into my resolv.conf. Rather than completely hard-codinging the settings on my laptop, can I override the settings *only* when I'm connecting to this jacked-up router?

I'm getting these settings in my resolv.conf from the Xfinity router:

```
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
search home.network
```

The `search home.network` in particular is a problem since I can't browse to https://github.com with this configuration, apparently because of this weird github.com.home.network entry:

```
$ nslookup github.com
Server:     75.75.75.75
Address:    75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com.home.network
Address: 127.0.53.53
```

I also use the laptop at work where there's a very specific network config, so I'm pretty sure if I just hard-code settings in my laptop and ignore the ones from DHCP, I'll have problems. Is there a way to fix my networking settings when connected to my home router without affecting them elsewhere?

Comment: BTW, I'd be totally fine just paying for better-behaved Xfinity-compatible networking equipment if that's a viable approach. I always have problems like this with big telco companies and their jacked-up networking equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling the wifi in the Xfinity router and connecting a real router in front of it, with custom DHCP configuration that specifies sane values.

It would be more satisfying to hack the Xfinity router and fix the configuration there, but this approach is easier and more flexible.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar with my TC8305C, I want to use my Linksys E3000 for wireless. Any chance you can share your setup steps, I'm guessing they'll be close to what I need?

Comment: Mine's a TL-WR740N, FWIW. I just went to DHCP > DHCP Settings, clicked Enable, and used Google's DNS servers for the primary and secondary DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Answer (score 2):

You can hack your router and change the settings in the router, so that when you receive the DNS settings from your router, you will have whatever you need.
Here is an article i wrote about one year ago, to help you to change the DNS settings for WiMAX CPE, its the same idea.

http://www.itprostuff.com/articles/change-dns-wimax-cpe.html

You need to find the telnet username / password for your router, and have a shell access, then go to the resolve.conf in the router and change the settings.

It does work very well. But for me, i could not make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue everybody else does with comcast's new modem/router combo. 
To fix this you will have to do what opendns says to do with the dns addresses on the network connections of each computer and here is the kicker: You have to go to the advanced button and then the DNS tab inside the network connections and uncheck both check boxes that are checked and then OK all the way out and recheck with Opendns website.